# Not found: Table project-id:employee_data.departments was not found in location US

Tags: sql, join, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

So I am trying to follow along with a tutorial on SQL joins but when I try to run the query in which I join two tables I get the aforementioned error.

I have confirmed that the dataset does indeed reside as you can see in the following screenshot:
[The dataset details page]

[image: 1]

The query in question is the following:

```
SELECT
    emp.name,
    dept.name,
    emp.name
FROM
    `project-id.employee_data.employees` as emp
INNER JOIN
    `project-id.employee_data.departments` as dept
ON
    emp.department_id = dept.department_id
```

If I try to query either table individually, I don't have any problems. It is only when I query them in the same place that it gives me an error. I made sure processing location is set to US in the query settings so location shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: are both tables in the same dataset?

Comment: @eshirvana Yes, both tables are in the same dataset

Comment: I'm just wondering why, in the error message, there is a colon after project-id, rather than a dot?

Comment: I'm not sure why but I tried replacing the dot with a colon to match the error message but it didn't work. It said it needed to be dots.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it worked out by removing the commas

`

```
FROM  

project-id.employee_data.employees as emp  

INNER JOIN  

project-id.employee_data.departments as dept`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm still getting the same error for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I am currently enrolled in the course, I noticed that when there is a space prior to the backtick at the end of the text string it will run.
For example: `project-id.employee_data.employees` as the table name gave me the same error, however when it is inputted as `project-id.employee_data.employees`  there was no error with the query.
(tip: copy the address from details and put it in backticks in the query)
Hope this helps anyone!